# Is there a special way to solder to these LED thermal pads?

Tags: led, soldering

[I don't know the correct names for these things, so please correct my vocab as needed.]

I just tried to solder a wire to the one of the rectangular contact areas on this LED. I'm a beginner hobbyist with a radio shack soldering iron, but usually I can solder wires okay.  But in this case the solder just balled up on the surface and refused to bind to it.  Is there a trick or a special way to connect these to wires?

[image]

Actual part is [here](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/LedEngin/LZ1-10R200/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu4Prknbu83y1kHJl487Qqnh7qFW6eM39A=)

Comment: Even for a beginner (which I am as well), I'd suggest against a RadioShack iron. The best cheap iron I've used that I'd recommend is: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9507. Maybe the solder didn't bind well because your iron can't get hot enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pad is thermally connected to the aluminium plate.  That's a byproduct of the LED cooling scheme.  As a result, it's harder to heat the pad with a soldering iron.  Until the pad is heated sufficiently, the solder will not stick to it.

- Heat the pad longer before actually trying to solder to it.
- Perhaps, use a larger tip in the soldering iron.
- Putting a drop of solder on the tip increases the contact area and improves heat transfer.
- If possible, pre-heat the whole board using a heat gun or a hot plate.  Temperature of the pre-heat should be much lower than melting point of the solder.
- Use leaded solder.  It has a lower melting point.

Comment: - use a better soldering iron.

Comment: Points 1 and 3 were enough to get it done. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry this is not the way to solder it.
This is like a SMD type.anyway good points , +1 for them.

Comment: My LEDs just burned out while connecting to my current source. I'm wondering if it's because I got them too hot by soldering with the iron like this, and if I should use a heat gun and paste instead.

Answer (score 2):

[Video on how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TetYxH5n_cw). You just didn't heat up the pad enough (and 25 W Radioshack iron is good enough for this).

Answer (score 1):

Those don't look like thermal pads, they're surface contacts for powering the LED. The actual thermal pad is underneath the LED and already soldered to the aluminum core PCB it's mounted on. However, since the board is metal core, it will conduct heat away faster than normal.

What's the wattage of your iron? I know I've done it easily with a 35W Weller iron, it may be more difficult with less power. Usual suggestions apply: be sure the iron is clean and the tip is tinned, use extra flux if the solder doesn't flow properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing, and I have fixed these LED's to a HAMADA printing machine.

The easiest way to solder this is take the LED and:

1. turn it other side and past some solder on the terminals. Very
   little, believe me very very very little. [you don't believe me very
   little do you? please very little].
2. Use a crocodile clip and temporary mount the  LED to the heat sink.
   Like this:

[image]

1. Heat up the terminals with your soldering bit, until lead spread
   through the surface unique.

Believe me surface tension is the force which applicable in here. That's what
glues LED to the heat sink. So use very little , very little soldering paste.

DISCLAIMER: Make sure that your soldering iron have no leakages. This is important when
soldering LED's. Because LED's have very little avalanche breakdown reverse voltage.This
is very important.If your LED will lit up while soldering then you already killed it 
up to some extend and it will not light in it's full light intensity.